# Failed to connect binance WebSocket api

Tags: python, websocket, cryptocurrency, binance

I am trying to connect to binance websocket API using python. But it fails with this error: `[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

```
import websocket
import sys
import pkg_resources

SOCKET = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m'

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('close connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error)
ws.run_forever()
```

Anyone has an idea how should I resolve the issue. Are their APIs reliable?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Binanic api change consistently with each upgrade to the API.  There a few ways of approaching the problem .

firstly check that the WSS socket is live ...

> SOCKET = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m'

Then

> A: check that you can log on manually through their documentation site as there live testing facility on there

If that is not  successful.

> B: Check that you API keys are still valid for account interaction
>
> C: check the api version they currently using
>
> E: on the API documentation there is live examples you can test the
> get requests
>
> D: Their service sometimes has limits on how often you can call their
> API Make sure you within range

Over an above that if you have tested their api live examples for get requests there no reason that is should not work . As a rule of thumb I always use postman or insomnia to check the requests before I implement it in my own code as sometimes your header in the post requests do not match their header requirements

[Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/)
or
[Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

I personally always use the insomnia first to make sure the requests work then implement it in my code to match the format .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add more query param, example like the one below

```
 {
  "id": "1dbbeb56-8eea-466a-8f6e-86bdcfa2fc0b",
  "method": "klines",
  "params": {
    "symbol": "BNBBTC",
    "interval": "1h",
    "startTime": 1655969280000,
    "limit": 1
  }
}
```

go to this url for more details of the necessary request and response https://developers.binance.com/docs/binance-trading-api/websocket_api#klines